# How to fix PyAutoGUI AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror, pyautogui

I Have been trying to get PyAutoGUI to click one of the applications at the bottom of my screen using a very simple code.  However, whenever I try to run this code I get an error that I believe is from the PyAutoGUI module I am using. The code is:

```
    import pyautogui as pag
    pag.click(500, 1100)
```

The error is:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 588, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 978, in click
    platformModule._multiClick(x, y, button, clicks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 516, in _multiClick
    core_graphics.CGEventPost(kCGEvent.Tap.value, mouseEvent)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 349, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: Tap
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out.  There is another command in the pyautogui module called pyautogui.mouseDown() and pyautogui.mouseUp().  If you uses these commands in sequence instead of pyautogui.click() it should work.
The working code:

```
import pyautogui as pag
pag.mouseDown(500, 1100, button='left')
pag.mouseUp(500, 1100, button='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of PyAutoGUI. This error happened for a few versions when we were changing the dependencies for macOS. This has been fixed in later versions of PyAutoGUI, so just run `pip3 install -U pyautogui`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(500, 1100, duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
```